# Excel Web Access can't find file

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm pretty new to sharepoint and I think there's a very easy solution to this question, but i just can't get it to work. I created a new Sharepoint Website which should contain an embedded excel file by excel web access. When I create this Excel Web Access, the Site says "Cannot find the file specified" but when I open the URL where the file is stored, I can download the file.

How is this possible? I don't think it's a permission problem, and I checked all preferences of Excel web access with another Website where we already embedded another excel file.

Can someone help me with this? thx!

I can provide a screenshot (unfortunately in german)

[image: File Not Found Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to save the file as xlsx, not xls. apparently old xls extension can not be shown in excel web access!